# Sudo asks for password twice with LDAP authentication

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, sudo

I have Ubuntu 8.04 LTS machine and Windows 2003 AD domain.

I have succesfully set up that I can log in with domain username and password, using domain prefix, like "domain+username".

Upon login to machine it all works first try, however, for some reason when I try to sudo my logged in user, it asks for the password *twice* every time when I try sudo. It accepts the password after 2nd time, but not the first time.

Once or twice I might think I just keep entering wrong pass the first time, but this is what happens always, any ideas of what's wrong?

pam.conf is empty
pam.d/sudo only includes common-auth & common-account, and

common-auth is:

```
auth    sufficient      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    sufficient      pam_winbind.so
auth    requisite       pam_deny.so
auth    required        pam_permit.so
```

Comment: note, that according to Samba documentation there are two similar options, which appear to do DIFFERENT things:

use_first_pass Do not prompt the user for passwords; take them from PAM_ items instead.
try_first_pass Try to get the password from a previous PAM module; fall back to prompting the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in PAM there is an option called "use_first_pass" :

```
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
```

try enabling it for ldap, should fix your issue

Comment: it appears that use_first_pass does something different? should it be try_first_pass?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this line:

```
auth    sufficient      pam_winbind.so
```

to

```
auth    sufficient      pam_winbind.so try_first_pass
```

Comment: Just to check: this won't make sudo asking for password twice, if I have to login with local account?

Comment: try_first_pass means try the password, and prompt if it fails. use_first_pass is more appropriate here. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=490210

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and removing:

```
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok
```

from /etc/pam.d/common-auth and adding:

```
auth sufficient pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
```

solved the problem :-).

Answer (score 0):

Besides from being an Ubuntu 14.04 installation, I had this same problem, which started after a failed `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` attempt in which I had to turn off the machine in the middle of the upgrade. Although in my case `/etc/pam.d/sudo` had:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

I just commented out `@include common-session-noninteractive` (i.e: adding a # in front of that line, like `# @include common-session-noninteractive`) and now everything is back to normal asking only once for the password when using sudo. So far so good. Hope this helps!